Fetch requests time out in a docker compose project but succeed after changes in frontend code
I have a multiple container project of two back-end APIs and a front-end SPA, which I build with docker compose via the command: sudo docker compose up --watch. I have set it up to do healthchecks to both APIs before starting the front-end container. In the front-end code, when the homepage loads, I am doing fetch requests to both APIs, to make sure it can reach them.
The problem is that these initial requests time out, but if I make a slight change in my front-end code, thus triggering a file sync and a hot-reload, the subsequent requests succeed just fine.
Why do I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on the initial requests?
Here is my compose.yaml file:
services:
  events_service:
    container_name: events
    build:
      context: ./events_service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    depends_on:
      - database
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3001/health"]
      interval: 20s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync
          path: ./events_service/src
          target: /app/events_service/src
          ignore:
            - node_modules/
        - action: rebuild
          path: ./events_service/package.json ./events_service/tsconfig.json

  venues_service:
    container_name: venues
    build:
      context: ./venues_service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    depends_on:
    - database
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3002/health"]
      interval: 20s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync
          path: ./venues_service/src
          target: /app/venues_service/src
          ignore:
            - node_modules/
        - action: rebuild
          path: ./venues_service/package.json ./venues_service/tsconfig.json

 frontend:
   container_name: frontend
   build:
     context: ./frontend
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
   ports:
     - "5173:5173"
   depends_on:
     events_service:
       condition: service_healthy
     venues_service:
       condition: service_healthy
   develop:
     watch:
       - action: sync
         path: ./frontend/src
         target: /app/frontend/src
       - action: rebuild
         path: ./frontend/package.json ./frontend/vite.config.ts /frontend/tsconfig.json

  database:
    container_name: database
    build:
      context: ./database
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"

The "events" service Dockerfile:
# Use the official Node.js 20 image
FROM node:20.12

# Install curl
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl 

# Install pnpm
RUN npm install -g pnpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app/events_service

# Install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN pnpm install

# Copy project files
COPY . .

# Expose port
EXPOSE 3001

# Run the application
CMD ["pnpm", "start"]

The "venues" service Dockerfile:
# Use the official Node.js 20 image
FROM node:20.12

# Install curl
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl 

# Install pnpm
RUN npm install -g pnpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app/venues_service

# Install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN pnpm install

# Copy project files
COPY . .

# Expose port
EXPOSE 3002

# Run the application
CMD ["pnpm", "start"]

The frontend Dockerfile:
# Use the official Node.js 20 image
FROM node:20.12

# Install pnpm
RUN npm install -g pnpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app/frontend

# Install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN pnpm install

# Copy project files
COPY . .

# Build project
# RUN pnpm 

# Expose port
EXPOSE 5173

# Run the application
CMD ["pnpm", "dev"]

And the fetch requests from the frontend:
fetch('http://172.17.0.1:3001/')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log('events check', res))

fetch('http://172.17.0.1:3002/health')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log('venues check', res))

where the 172.17.0.1 IP address is the docker address which I got by doing: ip addr | grep docker
